# Grails application running on Tomcat6 is reporting problems with registered JBDC driver

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-orm

I have developed an application in Grails. It uses Vaadin framework for GUI. It is running on Tomcat6 which is running on Ubuntu server.

Do you have any idea how to avoid these records in log files?

```
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@2818c2ce]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@719d76f2]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator$1@18ec4424]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator$1@18ec4424]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator$1@18ec4424]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator$1@18ec4424]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@2818c2ce]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@719d76f2]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator$1@18ec4424]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@2818c2ce]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/myapplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@719d76f2]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 18, 2011 12:05:47 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem in Tomcat6. It should be fixed in Tomcat7. See this for more info: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#customThreadLocal

And, this SEVERE shouldn't be harmless - see this conversation on Spring forum: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84202-Installation-ThreadLocal-forcefully-removed